# App server Log process

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hadoop2, flume, hadoop-streaming

I have a requirement from my client to process the application(Tomcat) server log file for a back end REST Based App server which is deployed on a cluster. Clint wants to generate "access" and "frequency" report from those data with different parameter.

My initial plan is that get those data from App server log --> push to Spark Streaming using kafka and process the data --> store those data to HIVE --> use zeppelin to get back those processed and centralized log data and generate reports as per client requirement.

But as per my knowledge Kafka does not any feature which can read data from log file and post them in Kafka broker by its own , in that case we have write a scheduler job process which will read the log time to time and send them in Kafka broker , which I do not prefer to do, as in that case it will not be a real time and there can be synchronization issue which we have to bother about as we have 4 instances of application server.

Another option, I think we have in this case is Apache Flume.

Can any one suggest me which one would be better approach in this case or if in Kafka, we have any process to read data from log file by its own and what are the advantage or disadvantages we can have in feature in both the cases?

I guess another option is Flume + kakfa together , but I can not speculate much what will happen as I have almost no knowledge about flume.

Any help will be highly appreciated...... :-)

Thanks a lot ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kafka Connect (file source connector) to read/consume Tomcat logs files & push them to Kafka. Spark Streaming can then consume from Kafka topics and churn the data

tomcat -> logs ---> kafka connect -> kafka -> spark -> Hive

Comment: kafka connect I guess will not be I am looking into as it will not be a good fit . I resolve this issue using flume sync with kafka. Thanks a lot for your reply.